# Django urlpatterns settings

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project, the working `urls.py` looks like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('polls/search', views.search, name='search'),

]
```

Then I want to add additional path for my image in the urls.py

```
urlpatterns += patterns('django.views.static',(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)','serve',{'document_root':settings.MEDIA_ROOT}), )
```

But I got:

```
 unresolved reference 'patterns'
```

I am using python 3.4 and Django 2.0.8. How do I properly add the additional path to my original urls.py ? Thanks!

Comment: `from django.conf.urls import patterns` got that?

Comment: doesn't work. Error: ImportError: cannot import name 'patterns'

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, you're trying to just add your media links to the urls right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like using `patterns` won't work anymore. Since you're trying to serve static files, try this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And set MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT in your settings.py.

In order to get it to work in your templates, you'd do something like this:

```
{% load static %}
<body data-media-url="{% get_media_prefix %}">
```

[Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-get_media_prefix)

Comment: Thanks. But the image still not showing: [22/Aug/2018 21:55:55] "POST /polls/polls/search HTTP/1.1" 200 852
Not Found: /polls/polls/{{MEDIA_URL}}my_img.jpg
[22/Aug/2018 21:55:55] "GET /polls/polls/%7B%7BMEDIA_URL%7D%7Dmy_img.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2582

Comment: well, yeah, the url shows that media_url wasn't resolved; I'll edit the question